# How do I set up keyboard shortcuts that use the Super key?

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys

I want the Super key to behave as a regular modifier key, just like Ctrl, Shift and Alt.

Currently, it doesn't.

Using the System Settings to set a shortcut like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> will set the shortcut, but the shortcut will be unusable. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> instead functions just like pressing a single Up. The Super modifier is ignored and the shortcut never gets activated. Likewise for shortcuts such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (i.e. it's like pressing an unmodified single W).

I've used CompizConfig to unbind all Unity-related shortcuts, but <kbd>Super</kbd> still behaves in this weird, special way.

How can I create keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> that work?

Answer (score 0):

`CCSM -> "Commands"` should work (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`).

There's also that dirty hack ..

Replacing "super" with "Mod4" in **~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/keybindings/custom0/%gconf.xml** seems to work after restarting X.

There might be compatibility issues if you bind already existing shortcuts, say "Mod4+Tab".